# Which StackExchange site would be appropriate to ask questions about Moodle server administration on?

Tags: discussion

Which StackExchange site would be appropriate to ask questions about Moodle server administration on?

I am unsure whether ServerFault, or perhaps Unix and Linux, or perhaps another SE site, would be more appropriate for such questions?

(I am also unsure as to whether there are (m)any knowledgeable Moodle admins who read SE regarding Moodle queries? Although Moodle's own forum community is very helpful, I am afraid to say that I find that trying to successfully search the Moodle forums for relevant information (to try to avoid the risk of asking questions which already have good answers) is rather awkward.)

Comment: ...I feel somewhat old when someone asks question about something in IT I *never heard about*...

Answer (score 1):

ServerFault seem to be the best target for such question, as we are almost the only site that got the tag [moodle created and used](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/moodle).

You can check past question to see if they were welcome or not, to see if your question could fit.